Problems in tracking redirect requests on Postman
I am trying to track how my POST request is being handled by a remote API. On Postman, I see that on making a POST request to /enter, I ultimately get a 200 response (after all redirections). Tracking the requests in Postman Console, I see this: 
Going by the order in which these appear in console, it seems that 1st POST req. (to /enter) redirected to second one (to /). However, on hovering over the redirection symbol (top right, above Show raw log), it says This request was triggered ON redirect. I am confused, since if this got triggered on redirect, which is the request that triggered it?
Also, in the image, I cannot find any field which indicates where this response redirects to. In another answer someone mentioned a field called referer but I can't find it anywhere, so how do we see that in Postman console?
The third issue is, when I turn off automatic redirects and perform the same POST requests in order (first to /enter, then to / with exact same fields as seen in this image), I receive 302 response in BOTH these requests. But sending a GET request to / after POST to /enter returns a successful 200 response (and performs the task that automatic redirect was doing). So why is there this discrepancy between Postman request logs and actual behavior?
I tried to track the requests that was made in browser when I submit the form at /enter:  As seen in image linked above, the referer of / was /enter and this is a GET request, not POST as shown in Postman. Why does Postman show this seemingly wrong redirection then?

Have you tried disabling the Automatically follow redirects setting to test this?

@DannyDainton Yes, when I manually made the POST request to /enter and /, I had switched off automatically follow redirects

There are other redirect based settings in the request settings, that will answer the questions about retaining the original HTTP methods

I don't want to retain the original methods, I just want to know why Postman shows it as POST request when it is a GET (if it automatically gets converted to GET request, why doesn't Postman show it?). Also, 'request triggered on redirect' is a language error, or am I misunderstanding it?

Key Takeaways and Solutions:

Understand the flow of redirections:**

For the initial POST /enter request:

The server responds with a 302 and a Location header (e.g., /).


Postman automatically follows this redirection with another POST request (unless configured otherwise).
Browsers typically change POST to GET when following a 302 redirect.


Inspect the redirection details:**

Disable automatic redirects in Postman to inspect the Location header in the 302 response.
Use this information to manually replicate the redirection flow.


Handling the discrepancy:**

If the API expects a GET request after redirection, configure Postman to mimic browser behavior or send the GET manually.


Session or state dependencies:**

Check if the server depends on cookies, headers, or other state information when handling redirects. Ensure these are preserved in manual requests.



By following these steps, you should be able to trace the behavior accurately

Your first point makes sense. But then why does Postman console show This request was triggered on redirect? Is this bad english/bug?

Also, your answer is clearly copy pasted from ChatGPT, so if you clean it up to remove unnecessary parts and confirm whether it is actually correct, it would be great!

Also, why does Postman show the redirected request as POST, if it gets converted to GET request?
